# Firefox plugin for quick text snippets inserting to forum posts

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins, firefox-extensions

Is there any plugin / extension for Firefox that allows quickly paste (and create) small text snippets, e.g. signature for forum posts, piece of HTML code with embedded avatar, etc.? Having this collection of snippets as a dropdown released from a button placed on Add-on bar would be just fine.

I've been searching through https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/ - but no success: either no similar tools OR they're not supported by latest FF 18.X.

Comment: If you know how to use javascript, you can use greasemonkey to create some simple script tha will eg. create aditional butons in editors.

Comment: @TomášZato unfortunately not - I'm not familiar with any programming language but VBA. Moreover, I don't think my wish is so rare and there's no such add-on for FF.

Comment: I had the same wish and I don't have the answer for it. I first decided to write script I was talking about and then I've forgotten about it at all. I hope you will have more luck. +1 for question should help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to preserver your snippets structure e.g avatars Or Email Icons etc then I'll recommend a more versatile software "**[PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/)**"

[image]

Beside your requirements this program has so many extra features. I advice to check some features [here](http://www.phraseexpress.com/benefits.htm).

Comment: "small text snippets, e.g. signature for forum posts, piece of HTML code with embedded avatar, etc." - means **PURE** HTML code, with links to pictures, NOT actual image files. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion - will take a look.

Comment: windows only :(